# PHPMailer, no errors

Tags: php, phpmailer, captcha, contact-form

Thanks for landing at my question.

I'm trying to build a contact form on a website i'm remotely hosting.

I want the form to have a captcha2 and to send a mail after the captcha has been tested successfully. For the mailing part i'm using "PHPMailer" The captcha works, the script is not returning errors yet no mails are recieved.

I've tried using the google mail servers but without success. Can anyone spot what it is i'm doing wrong? Here's my php code:

```
<?php
$privkey = "xxxx";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $url        = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $response   = file_get_contents($url."?secret=". $privkey . "&response=" . $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ."&remoteip=" .$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $data       = json_decode($response);

    if (isset($data->success) AND $data->success == true) {
        //VERIFIED CAPTCHA
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
        require '../scripts/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
            // validation expected data exists
            if (!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
                !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
                !isset($_POST['email']) ||
                !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
                !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
                died('Er is een probleem met de volledigheid van de informatie in uw contactformulier.'); //kill script
            }
            // var's for mailing based upon post input
            $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required 
            $last_name  = $_POST['last_name']; // required 
            $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required 
            $telephone  = $_POST['telephone']; // not required 
            $comments   = $_POST['comments']; // required

            // _POST DATA VALIDATION
            $error_message = "";
            // email
            $email_exp     = '/^(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22))(?:\.(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\]))$/iD';
            if (!preg_match($email_exp, $email_from)) {
                $error_message .= 'Het e-mailadres is niet geldig.<br />';
            }

            // NAME VALIDATION
            $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
            // first name
            if (!preg_match($string_exp, $first_name)) {
                $error_message .= 'Uw voornaam bevat niet toegestane leestekens.<br />';
            }
            // last name
            if (!preg_match($string_exp, $last_name)) {
                $error_message .= 'Uw achernaam bevat niet toegestane leestekens.<br />';
            }

            // message
            if (strlen($comments) < 2) {
                $error_message .= 'Het bericht is niet valide.<br />';
            }
            // STOP SCRIPT IF ERROR IS >0
            if (strlen($error_message) > 0) {
                died($error_message);
            }

            $email_message = "Bericht en gegevens hieronder.\n\n";

            function clean_string($string)
            {
                $bad = array(
                    "content-type",
                    "bcc:",
                    "to:",
                    "cc:",
                    "href"
                );
                return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
            }

            $email_message .= "First Name: " . clean_string(stripslashes($first_name)) . "\n";
            $email_message .= "Last Name: " . clean_string(stripslashes($last_name)) . "\n";
            $email_message .= "Email: " . clean_string(stripslashes($email_from)) . "\n";
            $email_message .= "Telephone: " . clean_string(stripslashes($telephone)) . "\n";
            $email_message .= "Comments: " . clean_string(stripslashes($comments)) . "\n";

            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 3; // Enable verbose debug output
            $mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host       = 'smtp.transip.email'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username   = '****@amplitudemusic.nl'; // SMTP username
            $mail->Password   = '*****'; // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
            $mail->Port       = 465; // TCP port to connect to
            $mail->setFrom('****@amplitudemusic.nl', 'name'); // Sender address
            $mail->addAddress('****@amplitudemusic.nl', 'name'); // Recipient 1
            $mail->addAddress('danny@amplitudemusic.nl', 'name'); // Recipient 2
            $mail->addReplyTo('****@amplitudemusic.nl', '{clean_string($first_name)} {clean_string($last_name)}'); // Reply Address

            $mail->Subject = 'contactformulier website';
            $mail->AltBody = '{$email_message}';

            if (!$mail->send()) {
                echo 'Message could not be sent.';
                echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                header('location: contact.php?CaptchaPass=True');
            } else {
                //not verified
                header('location: contact.php?CaptchaFail=True');
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
<html lang=nl>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Amplitude | Drive in Disco</title>

    <meta name="description" content="">

  <!-- Mobile-friendly viewport -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

   <!-- Style sheet link -->
    <link href="../css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body background="../img/background_website.png">
    <div id="background">
        <header role="banner" src="../index.php">
            <a href="../index.php" alt="Amplitude-Header"><img id="brand" src="../img/transparent.gif"/></a>
            <nav role="navigation" position="relative">
                <ul class="navbar" >
                    <li><a href="../index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="prijzen.php">Prijzen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <h2>Contact formulier</h2>
            <?php
if (isset($_GET['CaptchaPass'])) {
?>
               <h1>Uw mail is succesvol verzonden.</h1>
            <?php
}
?>
           <?php
if (isset($_GET['CaptchaFail'])) {
?>
               <h1>You did not pass the spam validator. Please try again.</h1>
            <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: *"the script is not returning errors"* - How sure are you about that? You're just using `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` which tests against an SMTP connection, but what about on the PHP side of things? what about the form for this? You sure that all those POST arrays evaluate? which also included `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've ran the script locally and i'm not getting any errors.

Also sorry for not including the gist url since i've made it but forgot to include it. For abbreviation's sake i've decided to stick with the php in a codeblock and for the html i wanted to refer to this link: 

https://gist.github.com/Thrizian/42dde0c489c04997867a6fa5afee298b

Comment: If you add `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of your script, and get no errors out, we will believe you

Comment: $mail->ErrorInfo will print the mail errors. you are not able to view the errors since you are redirecting to contact.php .
 `if (!$mail->send()) {
                echo 'Message could not be sent.';
                echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        //        header('location: contact.php?CaptchaPass=True');
            }`
Just comment the header line as shown and let me know

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't post that error reporting stuff anymore. I'm glad you did, but I just post a generic *"check for errors"*.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me out on my first php quest! I've altered lines 1 and 96 and 99 to match your request, rerun the script and tried submitting again Still i've experienced no errors and the page redirects to itself (without the "Captchapass=True" or "Captchafail=True" post value) shown after filling out and submitting the form. The settings in my php.ini are set to show all errors.

Comment: Just to be sure this is clear, i did add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of the script. @Orchid & @RiggsFolly

Comment: Have you commented the line `// header('location: contact.php?CaptchaPass=True'); `

Comment: @Orchid yes i have!

Comment: So, all i've gotten now is people stating that i don't have the proper error display settings, which i have. I've also followed suggestions but none of this solves the issues i'm having. I'd love a reply from someone who actually plans on helping me in the solution of this issue. No errors, no e-mails recieved. What could be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was the order in which arguments were passed to PHPmailer after initializing the "$mail = new PHPMailer;".

Which should be:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug    = 3;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.yourserver.topleveldomain'; 
$mail->Port       = yourportnumber;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'yourprotocol';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = 'SmtpUsername';
$mail->Password   = 'SmtpPassword';
$mail->setFrom(     'sender@domain.tld', 'Sender Name')
$mail->addReplyTo(  $email_from, '{clean_string($first_name)}{clean_string($last_name)}');
//repeat the next line for multiple  recipients.
$mail->addAddress('user@domain.tld', 'Recipient Name');
$mail->Subject = 'mail subject';
$mail->Body = $email_message;
```

I've also used different variable to pass the body argument to:

```
    $mail->AltBody = '{$email_message}';
```

which is now

```
    $mail->Body = $email_message;
```

Also the redirect from the validator was blocking all error codes from showing up. Commenting out the Captcha2 php code made spotting them easy.